# Что за символы и как их удалить?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, запрашиваю у игрового сервера данные (неважно какого, через каждый другой сервер иероглифы) название сервера. И получаю в ответ:

�b�L --->�6�L -Evolution World-�b�L <---

Хотя должен:  ---> -Evolution World- <--- (Смотрю с другого сайта)

Использую скрипт:

https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query

Даже если использовать другой скрипт то все равно иероглифы есть...

Спасибо, за последующую помощь!!!

Comment: Какие-то спец символы, закодированные в Юникод. Возможно неразрывные пробелы или что-то типа того

Comment: Ага, только как от них избавится правильным и разумным способом? Конечно требую я от вас многое, эдак написать уже готовый скрипт, но всетаки я бы был благодарен хоть за один пример решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Вы смотрите протокол, это, похоже, не мусор, а служебная информация. Соответственно надо аккуратно смотреть и её удалять ("так, тут 4 байта - тип пакета, надо проверить, что он - тот, который я жду; дальше: 4 байта - размер, мне не нужно; ...") [https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol][1] 

[1]: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

Переконвертируйте полученный результат.

```
//функция iconv() смены кодировки с windows-1251 на UTF-8

//если исходный текст в кодировке windows-1251
$text1251 = "Тестовое сообщение";
$textutf8 = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $text1251);

echo $textutf8;
```

Comment: Поверьте я пробовал именно таким способом, получаем следующие: §b§l..:: §4§lMega§1§lCraft §b§l::..

Comment: Методом тыка я смастерил следующее: 

$name = preg_replace('/§.{1}/i', '', $name);

Как можно это оптимизировать?